# How to terminate backround processes using bash script

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

I am trying to write a script which will book up a local Kafka cluster to speed up my development process. I was able to book up the environment but I am having trouble automating the tear down of the cluster.

What the cluster contains:

1. A zookeeper instance
2. 2 Kafka Brokers

Below is the script I am running

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to Kafka server directory
KAFKA_SERVER_DIR="./kafka-3.7.0-src"
cd "$KAFKA_SERVER_DIR" || exit
PID_FILE="kafka_pids.txt"

rm -rf /tmp/kafka-logs /tmp/kafka-logs1 /tmp/zookeeper /tmp/kraft-combined-logs
# Function to start Kafka Zookeeper
start_zookeeper() {
    echo "Starting Kafka Zookeeper..."
    bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
}

# Function to create Kafka broker
create_broker() {
    local config_file="$1"
    echo "Creating Kafka broker with config $config_file "
    bin/kafka-server-start.sh "$config_file"
}

make_topic() {
    local topic_name="$1"
    local replication_factor="$2"
    local num_partitions="$3"

    bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic "$topic_name" --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor $replication_factor --partitions $num_partitions
}

start_zookeeper &
sleep 1 # give it a second
echo $! >> "$PID_FILE"


# Start first broker
create_broker "config/server.properties" &
echo $! >> "$PID_FILE"
sleep 2 # let it finish initializing

# Start the second broker
create_broker "config/server1.properties" &
echo $! >> "$PID_FILE"
sleep 2

make_topic "test_topic" 2 3 2 > make_topic_error.log &
echo $! >> "$PID_FILE"
```

How I would manually shut down this cluster is the following:

1. Go to one of the brokers (doesn't matter which one) and do Command +C
2. After that broker has properly shut down, shut down the other broker by also doing command + C
3. Once the second broker is shut down, I do Command + C on Zookeper and that is the final step

I am trying to automate this but have had no luck

As you can see I am writing to a file what I believed to be the PID's of each of these processes. However, running a script which runs "kill" on those PID's doesnt work.

I am not sure why but there are a bunch different PID's I see when I do

`lsof -i:<port>`

When I manually go and kill all of those PID's then it actually shuts down.

How can I properly automate the shutdown of this cluster using a bash script?

Comment: Don't use self-daemonizing entrypoints (like your `start_zookeeper &` here) at all. This is what proper process supervision is for -- set up a proper systemd service or other equivalent as supported by your OS vendor. Once systemd or launchd or whatnot knows about your service it's a `systemctl start yourservice` or `systemctl stop yourservice` or `systemctl restart yourservice` or so forth to change its status, you can make systemd be responsible for startup on boot, &c.

Comment: (systemd supports `type=forking` to be able to track a self-daemonizing entrypoint if you _really insist_ on using the upstream script, but using `start-foreground` instead of `start` makes doing that unnecessary and lets the default `type=simple` work, as well as functioning with a wider array of other process supervision tools)

Comment: ...similarly, systemd _also_ lets you set up dependencies -- saying "X must be started after Y", or "if X restarts, all of A B and C need to be restarted too". It's very much the Right Thing, for this task and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can send signal to all processes in process group by preceeding PID number with dash. For example send term to process with pid 12345678 and all processes in group.

```
kill -s SIGTERM -12345678
```